# How to separate concerns between model and view in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, coding-style, laravel-blade

I'm trying to come up with clean code for my simple Laravel application. I have a view (`user.blade.php`) to display user details:

```
<div class="name">
    <label>Name</label>
    <span class="value">{{ $user->name }}</span>
</div>
<div class="address">
    <label>Address</label>
    <span class="value">
        <span class="line1">{{ $user->address_line_1 }}</span>
        @if ($user->address_line_2 !== null)
            <span class="line2>>{{ $user->address_line_2 }}</span>
        @endif
    </span>
</div>
<div class="phone">
    <label>Phone numbers</label>
    <span class="value">
        @if ($user->phone_main !== null)
            <span class="main">{{ $user->phone_main }}</span>
        @endif
        @if ($user->phone_alt !== null)
            <span class="alt">{{ $user->phone_alt }}</span>
        @endif
    </span>
</div>
```

Some users have only one address line, some have two (which I model using two columns, `address_line_1` and `address_line_2`, this latter being nullable), some have 0 phone numbers, others have 1 or 2 (again two columns, `phone_main` and `phone_alt`, both of which are nullable).

Since I want a properly formatted address line and phone number information, I'm using the blade `@if` directives to ensure that the `<span>`s only appear if they contain any information. Best practices (as far as I'm aware) dictate that the view should not "do so much", but I don't think I can properly encapsulate this behaviour in an eloquent attribute (`function getFormattedAddressAttribute` in the `User` class), because I'm wrapping the elements in HTML tags, and I don't want my model to know about HTML.

My question is: what is the general guideline to deal with this situation? Should I:

1. keep my solution?
2. pull the parts of the view that render the address and the phone numbers into partial views and include them in this main view?
3. do something else?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, in your controller you could write a variable that creates your formatted address for you.

```
$formattedAddress = $user->address_line_1;

if($user->address_line_2 !== null){
  $formattedAddress .= "<br>" . $user->address_line_2;
}
```

And same with the phone numbers. You can return these with your view:

```
return view ('user.details')->with("formattedAddress", $formattedAddress);
```

Obviously will need to be styled to your taste and requirements, but that might work for you.